# Select inside an if else or case sql expression

Tags: sql, select, if-statement, case

I would like to make a select expression inside a if else or case expression, but I can't get it to work.

I have tried the folowing

```
select
(case when DateTime1 is null then select * from LogEntries where PC_TID > '2014-03-26'
else select * from LogEntries where DateTime1 > '2014-03-26' 
end) as timeSearchParam
from LogEntries
```

and this

```
if DateTime1 is null
begin
select * from LogEntries where PC_TID > '2014-03-26' 
end
else
begin
select * from LogEntries where DateTime1 > '2014-03-26' 
end
```

None of them worked and I just can't figure out, what the problem is.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is

```
select * from LogEntries where PC_TID > '2014-03-26'  and DateTime1 is null
union all
select * from LogEntries where DateTime1 > '2014-03-26'  and DateTime1 is not null
order by coalesce(DateTime1 , PC_TID)
```

or

```
select * from LogEntries 
where 
(PC_TID > '2014-03-26'  and DateTime1 is null)
or
(DateTime1 > '2014-03-26'  and DateTime1 is not null)
order by coalesce(DateTime1 , PC_TID)
```

Comment: I need to sort the data by DateTime1 and if this is null I have to use PC_TID. Your suggestion will return both will it not?

Comment: I have modified the code. Please refer it and see if it works

Comment: have tried it out and it seems that it works, thanks :-)